# gaierror-2,Name or service name not known) when using requests.post in python

Tags: python, linux, python-requests

I am trying to send web request to my php code via linux running on raspberry pi. I am using putty to access the OS. When I am running the code, I am getting gai error-2. Below is my code:

```
import requests

values = {'"firstname":' "abc ", '"lastname":' "xyz"}
r = requests.post('http://rts.msmq.site/security.php', data=values)
```

I am unable to figure out the problem. Can someone let me know what could be the issue? I am using linux.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 94, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))
```

Comment: Are you able to send this "request"  from cmdline? 
 : "*http://rts.msmq.site/security.php*"

Comment: @CristiFati  Yes, ping is successful and nslookup returns: Server: UnKnown Address: 2a02:908:2:a::1 Non-authoritative answer: Name: rts.msmq.site Address: 50.87.147.175

Comment: You aren't posting a Python dictionary... The colons should not be in quotes. Can you make a request with Postman, for example?

Comment: @cricket_007 What is postman?>

Comment: I trust your ability to search for that

Answer (score 1):

gaierror stands for get_address_info_error, which means urllib is having trouble reaching the hostname 'http://rts.msmq.site/security.php', check that you can `nslookup rts.msmq.site` or `dig rts.msmq.site` and `ping rts.msmq.site`

Comment: Yes, ping is successful and nslookup returns: Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2a02:908:2:a::1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    rts.msmq.site
Address:  50.87.147.175

Comment: Don't rush into answering questions, before having the answer!

Comment: @Marium - `Server: UnKnown Address` is the issue

Comment: @Marium Looks like a DNS error, which is a network problem. Nothing you can do about it in code

Comment: @cricket_007 but I can access this php file from other platforms like Matlab and Simulink

Comment: if ping is not working for this particular url, try another one.
possible problems : the url is not correct so it's notreachable from the machine your using
or the machine is not configured to access any other urls